# "synthetic", what definition would this adjective fall under?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Let's say, we are listening to a lecture about impressionism.

The professor says,

> Why would imressionists depart from previous artistic standard to create works that were so radically different? The key lies in the discovery and mass production of industrial paints. Prior to the industrial revolution, artists had to mix colors of paint themselves -- a process that was labor-intensive and kept them tied to their studios. In contrast to this, pre-mixed, ***synthetic*** paint, sold in tubes not unlike that of toothpaste today, allowed artists to work en-plein air.

Merriam Unabridged says,

Adjective ***synthetics***

> 1 a :  relating to or involving synthesis
>
> b :  not analytic
>
> 2
>   a :  attributing to a subject a predicate that is not contained in the essence of that subject
>
> b :  having the truth determined by observation or the facts of experience
>
> c :  not resulting in a contradiction upon being negated
>
> 3
>   of a language :  characterized by synthesis :  inflectional
>   
>   — called also analytic
>
> 4
>   a :  of, relating to, or being a taxonomic category retained for reasons of convenience but not regarded as constituting a natural unit
>
> b :  of, relating to, or being a group deliberately produced by combining genes 
>   in a manner unlikely to occur in nature
>
> 5
>   of an organ stop :  composed of two or more pipes for each tone
>
> 6
>   a :  produced by artificial processes either from relatively simple substances or from naturally occurring sometimes complex substances :  man-made
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   — compare semisynthetic
>
> b :  devised, arranged, or fabricated for special situations to imitate or replace usual realities
>   
>   
>   :  employing or concerning such devices or fabrications instead of actualities
>
> c :  patently produced or maintained by special effort and therefore often forced, constrained, distorted, or simulated :  not natural or spontaneous :  spurious, factitious
>
> 7
>   of cubist art :  involving the composing of pictorial objects without the restrictions of natural appearances or relations — opposed to analytical — compare cubism

I guess in this context that adjective's definition would fall under 6a?

Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: Spelling: "en plein air"  because this is a borrowed expression from French, we use the French spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> produced by artificial processes

Paints used to be made from all sorts of strange things: Coloured soil from particular valleys in Italy, blue rocks imported from Afghanistan, crushed bugs, even human mummies from Egypt. Painters would obtain these pigments, turn them into powder, mix with egg, oil or gum, and paint with them. (Some artists were poisoned by the pigments that they used).

Synthetic paint is made in the chemistry lab. Pigments are artificially made by from chemicals and sold pre-mixed in tubes. The most famous synthetic pigment is "ultramarine", the synthetic version of the blue pigment in Lapis Lazuli.